# Rails rake assets:precompile failing when compiling application.css.scss

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have a rails version 3.2.17 application I am trying to run locally, when I run rails server
and then hit the root page I get an error that says,

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound at /
couldn't find file 'jquery.Jcrop'
```

for application.css.scss

So after attempting to recompile the assets in hopes of solving the problem I get an error that says

```
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'plupload.full'
```

for application.js

after running
    bundle exec rake assets:precompile
    rake assets:precompile
    rake assets:precompile:all
none of which work and throw the same error.

I'm using Sprockets 2.2.2 and this appears to be the issue, any ideas what could be wrong?

Edited: Including application.js, application.css.scss, and root page

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.validate
//= require jquery.validate.defaults
//= require plupload.full
//= require jquery.Jcrop
//= require fancybox
//= require flowplayer.min
//= require player
//= require scripts
//= require lessons
//= require practices
//= require profiles
//= require orders
//= require_tree ./theme
//= require devise
```

application.css.scss

```
//= require theme/bootstrap
//= require theme/accordian
//= require theme/alt_footer
//= require theme/docs
//= require theme/prettyPhoto
//= require theme/slider
//= require theme/socialist
//= require theme/timeline
//= require theme/zocial

//= require jquery.Jcrop
//= require fix_thumbnails
//= require fancybox
//= require flowplayer.skin
//= require player
//= require styles

//= require devise
//= require pages
//= require lessons
//= require home
//= require practices
//= require profiles
//= require order_items
//= require orders

//= require fontello
//= require picons
```

root application.html.haml

```
%html(lang="en")
  %head
    %meta(charset="utf-8")
    %meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1")
    %meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    %title= content_for?(:page_title) ? yield(:page_title) : 'Tweak'
    = csrf_meta_tags
    / Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements
    /[if lt IE 9]
      = javascript_include_tag '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.1/html5shiv.js'
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => 'all'
    = favicon_link_tag 'favicon.png'
    %link{href: "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400|Montserrat", rel: "stylesheet", type: "text/css"}/

  %body.full-layout
    .body-wrapper
      .yamm.navbar.basic.default
        .navbar-header
          .container
            .basic-wrapper
              .dropdown
                %a.btn.responsive-menu.pull-right.dropdown-toggle#icon-bar{ data: {toggle: "dropdown", target: "#"}}
                  %i.icon-menu-1
                %ul.dropdown-menu{role: 'menu', aria: {labelledby:"icon-bar"}}
                  = render 'shared/primary_links'

              = link_to logo_image_tag, user_signed_in? ? my_lessons_path : root_path, class: "navbar-brand"
            .collapse.navbar-collapse.pull-right
              %ul.nav.navbar-nav
                = render 'shared/primary_links'
            %ul.dropdown-menu{role: 'menu', aria: {labelledby:"icon-bar"}}
              = render 'shared/primary_links'
      = render 'shared/messages'
      = yield
      = render 'shared/footer'

    = render 'shared/auth_modals'
    /
      Javascripts
      \==================================================
    / Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = yield(:script) if content_for?(:script)
```

Comment: show both `application.css.scss` & `application.js` and `application.html.erb` or main layout from `app/views/layouts/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting the files it said were missing it I was able to start up the server correctly.